# How to derive the variance of a point estimator that contains another estimator?

Tags: variance

I am trying to derive an variance estimator $var(\hat{\theta}(\mu,x))$ for an point estimator $\hat{\theta}(\mu,x)$, where $\mu$ is the true mean, $x$ is the data.

Now I need to replace the true mean $\mu$ with the sample mean $\hat{\mu}$. Then what is the general approach to incorporate this extra variability of sample mean $\hat{\mu}$ in computing $var(\hat{\theta}(\mu,x))$?

Any reference, comment or suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: Use the delta method, based on  a 2 variable Taylor expansion.

Comment: Thanks, Kimchi. I thought about that. But this scenario is not a combination of two different estimators. it is one is nested within the other one.

Comment: As in, $\hat\theta$  explicitly depends on (say) $\bar x$ and $\mu$, and $\hat\mu$  also depends on $\bar x$ and some other $x$-based sample average?  Unroll it into an expression $\hat \theta = f( \overline{\text{this}}, \overline{\text{that}})$...